# numetriclabz / numandroidchart how to space out the bars in a stacked bar chart / stacked percentage column chart

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am trying to create a 100% stacked bar chart in android using [numetriclabz / numandroidchart](https://github.com/numetriclabz/numAndroidCharts) library.

I have been able to draw the chart successfully but I want to format some things to make it look better since right now it is looking cluttered, so I tried to find the solution but to no avail.

I have a few questions and it would be great if you guys can help me out :

- How can I seperate out the bars in a stacked bar chart / stacked
  percentage column chart ?
- How can I change the colors of the bars?
- How can I draw a trendline in a stacked bar chart ?
- How to put a label inside the bar?
- How can I remove the description at the bottom if I want to?
- Is there any other chart library that I should use to help myself in this, I have used mpandroidchart library but I dont know if it has a trendline which is required in this project.

Here is the code of my mainactivity.java :

```
package com.example.android.testingbarchart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts.ChartData;
import com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts.StackedBarChart;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    StackedBarChart Chart;
    List<ChartData> value;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Chart = (StackedBarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        value = new ArrayList<>();

        Float[] value1 = {2f,3f,6f };
        Float[] value2 = {3f,5f,7f };

        value.add(new ChartData(value1, "Jone"));
        value.add(new ChartData(value2, "Joe"));

        List<String> h_lables = new ArrayList<>();
        h_lables.add("sun");
        h_lables.add("mon");
        h_lables.add("tue");

        Chart.setLabels(h_lables);

        Chart.setPercentageStacked(true);

        Chart.setData(value);

        Chart.setDescription("");



//        Chart.setHorizontal_label(h_lables); deprecated

//        List<ChartData> trendzone = new ArrayList<>();
//        trendzone.add(new ChartData(14f, 17f,"Target Range"));
//        Chart.setTrendZones(trendzone);
//
//        Chart.setDescription("");
//
//        Chart.setGesture(false);

    }

}
```

and here is the [image while testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Twe.png) since I am not allowed to post images yet so I posted the link.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: I suggest you to use `MPAndroidChart` library.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/StackedBarActivity.java (Class file) and https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/res/layout/activity_barchart.xml (xml file) here.

Comment: I have actually used the mpandroidchart library but I think it does not have the trendline which i need.

Comment: I suggest you to raise issue in `MPAndroidChart` library and ask Philipp Jahoda for trendline.